# How can I add an UISerachBar to an UIToolBar?

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, uitoolbar

I try now something like this:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIViewController *searchBarContainer = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithFrame:searchBar.frame];
[searchBarContainer addSubview:searchBar];

NSArray* buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fixed, searchBarContainer, nil];

[detailToolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIBarButtonItem  * searchBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar];

UIToolbar  * searchToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0+20,[self view].bounds.size.width,32)];

[searchToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchBarButtonItem,homeButtonItem, nil] animated:YES];
```